# sql nested join inner and left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hi I want to filter logs using MySQL with a list of trackings.

Every log belongs to a server,

Every tracking belongs to a server and have 0..N patterns

Every pattern belongs to a tracking

I have 3 tables :

```
logs     : |  id  |      ip     | url     | server_id | ...
tracking : |  id  | server_id   | name    | other fields...
pattern  : |  id  | tracking_id | pattern |
```

I want to count logs that match tracking for a specific server my problem is that my query mix up tracking that have pattern and those that don't.

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f11b1/2

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logs.ip), tr.name
FROM `logs`
INNER JOIN `trackings` as tr ON 
        ( tr.server_id = logs.server_id )
        AND -- OTHER conditions between log and tracking
    LEFT JOIN `patterns` as pt ON 
        ( pt.tracking_id = tr.id )
        AND (logs.url LIKE pt.pattern )
GROUP BY tr.id
```

My problem is on the second join, if I use `INNER JOIN patterns as pt ON` I get correct results but only on trackings that have some patterns,
If I use `LEFT JOIN patterns as pt ON` I get all tracking but with a false count (I get the result of `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logs.ip) FROM logs` )

**EDIT**
I Can get the correct result with a field in tracking that indicates if the tracking has patterns and a UNION :

```
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lg.ip), tr.name
FROM `logs` as lg
INNER JOIN `trackings` as tr ON 
        ( tr.server_id = lg.server_id )
        AND (tr.hasPatterns = 1)
        AND -- Other conditions
    INNER JOIN `patterns` as pt ON 
        ( pt.tracking_id = tr.id )
        AND (lg.url LIKE pt.pattern )
WHERE
GROUP BY tr.id
)
UNION
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lg.ip), tr.name
FROM `logs` as lg
INNER JOIN `trackings` as tr ON 
        ( tr.server_id = lg.server_id )
        AND (tr.hasPatterns = 0)
WHERE
GROUP BY tr.id, lg.date
)
```

But I guess there is a way to do that without using Union...

Comment: Can you provide us with a show create table statements and some test data maybe on sql friddle? that way we can help better

Comment: It's unclear what results you expect and what you get instead. Provide sample data and desired output based on it.

Comment: Yes you're right here it is : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f11b1/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a conditional inside `count`, so I think the following does what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (case when tr.hasPatterns = 1 and pt.tracking_id is not null
                            then lg.ip
                            when tr.hasPatterns = 0
                            then lg.ip
                       end)), tr.name
FROM `logs` as lg
INNER JOIN `trackings` as tr ON 
        ( tr.server_id = lg.server_id )
        AND -- Other conditions
    LEFT JOIN `patterns` as pt ON 
        ( pt.tracking_id = tr.id )
        AND (lg.url LIKE pt.pattern )
WHERE
GROUP BY tr.id
```

EDIT:

This is returning what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (case when tr.size = 0 and pt.tracking_id is not null
                            then lg.ip
                            when tr.size > 0 and lg.size > tr.size
                            then lg.ip
                       end)), tr.name
FROM `logs` as lg
INNER JOIN `trackings` as tr ON 
        ( tr.server_id = lg.server_id )
    LEFT JOIN `patterns` as pt ON 
        ( pt.tracking_id = tr.id )
        AND (lg.url LIKE pt.pattern )
GROUP BY tr.id;
```

Your SQL Fiddle has the additional condition `lg.size > tr.size` which is not in the original question.

Comment: Yes thanks, your edit do the trick, could you explain why you have to use a condition in DISTINCT ?

Comment: @Arnaud . . . You have to use the condition in the `count(distinct)` to separate out the two cases.  To get an understanding, play with the query removing the condition and see what happens.